# Complicate security rules

Tags: security, permissions, acl, portal, branding

I have been tasked with something that seems a challenge in the security world. The problem is to build a website that has:

1. Complex ACLs and view permissions. eg. A customer's transaction history should only be displayed in a portal for the customer support agents.
2. Multi-branded. eg. If the customer support agent is Microsoft then they should have access only to that subset of users and to have the site look'n'feel match their brand. If the agent is Apple then do likewise with their customers and brand.

Item #1 is standard security. Item #2 (multi-branding) seems to overcomplicate things.

To meet the above requirements it seems that each portal and access request will need to take into account things such as: brand being viewed, user roles, objects and their membership to a given brand.

How do I go about tackling the above? Is there any literature on how to build a secure, multi-branded site?